# Copy sqlite database table to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

Is there a way to copy my local sqlite database table into my postgres database on production? I'm very new to Rails so any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Trucker](https://github.com/mokolabs/trucker) would seem to fit the bill for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tool to export data from Sqlite and import it to Postgres. You can use https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps.

Here is a tutorial for this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You can use [taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps)

**notice**

I saw you have a question about heroku a few day before. Does this question involved with Heroku? If so, you should not use sqlite locally and postgres remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) for dumping and loading data. Easy to use.